# Subtotal in microsoft query (Xxcel)

Tags: excel, database-connection

I am new to Microsoft Query in Excel. I need to subtotal Column two by categories in Column one. Similar to [Sum function] and [Group by]  in in SQL. I'd rather not just throw the query into excel and use a pivot table, because I have over a million records of data. Can anyone assist in the process of creating the subtotals?

Comment: What SQL have you tried? `select colOne, sum(colTwo) as sumColTwo group by colOne` should do it.

Comment: Well I'm wanting to use Microsoft Query in Excel to pull form the SQL server. Trying to do the same concept as SQL, but in MQ. I have since learned that you can export the query directly into a pivot table so the data isn't being stored in the workbook. Maybe that will work ok,

Comment: Isn't MQ really just a wizard to help you create SQL?  If you're comfortable with using SQL then why go through that process?

Comment: I suppose MQ is SQL in a way, but its a convenient conduit to automating some of my processes. Because I don't want to open Management Studio and query a million records, export the file, and create a link or reference another workbook. I'd rather have some of that automated inside the workbook I'm using. MQ reads the tables and allows for some filtering, joins, and mathematical expressions; and Some MS resources say that subtotaling is possible before sending to worksheet, but no steps are provided. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: The SQL I posted (or something similar) does exactly what you're looking for: it only retrieves the summarized data.  I assumed that since you mentioned SQL in your question you were familiar with it.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstanding...familiar with SQL just new to MQ. I was able to edit the SQL query in MQ to add sum and group by. Works perfect! thanks

Answer (score -1):

Select the SQL button in MQ. Your SQL statement will appear in a separate window, where you can edit the query in SQL.